# Only rewrite directory if successfully rewrote parent directory

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Say I had this URL:

http://mywebsite.com/forum/thread/129

I want to rewrite to:

http://mywebsite.com/index.php?area=forum&page=thread&threadid=129

How can I achieve this without defining every possible sub-directory combination?

Here's what I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$    index.php?area=$1&page=$2&threadid=$3   [NC,L]
```

and a few other attempts, all futile.

This is what I've ended up with (and works):

```
RewriteRule ^forum/?$                       index.php?area=forum                                [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/thread/?$                index.php?area=forum&page=thread                [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forum/thread/(.*)/?$       index.php?area=forum&page=thread&threadid=$1            [NC,L]
```

How can I achieve what I want to do?

The URL params can be left empty. They'll be ignored by my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*)(?:/([^/]*))?)?/?$ /index.php?area=$1&page=$2&threadid=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Thought its not clear what you mean by: `Is there some regex that will only try and match the next sub-directory if it matches the first one?`

Comment: Thanks, it almost works! It 404's on the first level directory, but works with every sub-directory (in my example I would be able to view a specific thread). Also it only works when you include a backslash - can that be optional? I tried using /? with no luck.

Comment: Please provide examples of every case it didn't work. I can suggest a way out.

Comment: mysite.com/forum/ does not exist. mysite.com/forum/thread/ does. mysite.com/forum/thread does not exist. mysite.com/forum/thread/ does (note the backslash).

Comment: So you want to redirect `mysite.com/forum/thread/` also? What should be redirected URI? Would that be: `/index.php?area=forum&page=thread&threadid=`?

Comment: Okay my example was poor/too simple, so here's how it's actually being used: http://pastebin.com/JNHNSVPY

Comment: I am still not clear on your requirement. Should `/post/view` be rewritten as `/index.php?area=post&page=view&threadid=`

Comment: Yes. The extra params will be ignored by the script.

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks a bunch!